# Icon positioning in div - ignore text whitespace

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I am trying to position an icon inside a div with text.

The icon should stick to the top right corner no matter how much lines of text are inside. How can I achieve that?

```css
.box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

span {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="box">
  This is a sample text inside a sample box. 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  This is a sample text. 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28n4kprv/1/)

Comment: @Paulie_D I appreciate your way of helping, this will make OP think and do R&D before asking question here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.box{
    display: flex;
}
span{
    margin-left: auto
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that without using `position:absolute`.

```css
.box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  margin-left:auto;
  color: red;
  padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box">
  This is a sample text inside a sample box.
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hows this? position the box class relative and create a new div to hold the icon and position that absolute, where to then set a top and right position of 0px.

```
.box {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
}


.box .ico-holder{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

span {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}


https://jsfiddle.net/28n4kprv/10/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reordering your `box` markup slightly by moving the `<span>` icon before the text can give you the effect you're going for.

```css
.box {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 160px; 
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

span {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      This is a sample text inside a sample box.
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      This is a sample text. 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```